# How to run a folder of angular from a project

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8auy.jpg)When I give ng serve command from the directory it does not run and returns back to the directory.

How can I run angular project

Comment: Can you please put some screenshot of error for the same?

Comment: I have added the picture.

Answer (score 0):

ng serve runs all the project and allow you to see changes do you. while working on project.

Most probably when you download angular you haven't downloaded all needed parts.

Check on your terminal node version: node -v

It should give you a version.

[image]

Check Angular version: ng version

You should get something like that:
[image]

If you cant get versions, then you probably need to download them first.

If they all looks good,

1. You should have to be the exact project folder. I you use vs code I suggest using its own terminal

[image]

2. After hitting ng serve, don't close the terminal. if you need terminal again you can open more with the tick + button

[image]

Comment: Ya I did this but nothing happened. Can you please check the image link in the question.

Comment: then your project is not right. you have missed some files or even location

Comment: can you please tell what file might be missing

Comment: you need to put screenshot